# How can I move correctly data from httpClient.get to my local variable

Tags: angular, observable

I've written some code for getting menu items from a database to my angular app. The Rest Service works fine, returning the following result:

```
[{"childmenu":"","doktype":1,"id":44,"itemtext":"Yardstickzahlen"},{"childmenu":[{"childmenu":"","doktype":1,"id":47,"itemtext":"Formular"},{"childmenu":"","doktype":1,"id":48,"itemtext":"Ausfüllhilfe"}],"doktype":4,"id":43,"itemtext":"Deklaration"},{"childmenu":[{"childmenu":"","doktype":1,"id":45,"itemtext":"Gruppenbildung"},{"childmenu":"","doktype":1,"id":41,"itemtext":"Proteste"}],"doktype":4,"id":39,"itemtext":"Empfehlungen"},{"childmenu":[{"childmenu":"","doktype":1,"id":49,"itemtext":"Einführung"},{"childmenu":"","doktype":1,"id":40,"itemtext":"Vergütungen"},{"childmenu":"","doktype":1,"id":42,"itemtext":"Abkürzungen"}],"doktype":4,"id":46,"itemtext":"Dokumentation"},{"childmenu":"","doktype":1,"id":50,"itemtext":"Impressum"}]
```

Here is the component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

import { MenuService} from "../menu.service";
import {MenuItems} from "../models/menu-items";
import { __values } from 'tslib';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.css']
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _menu : MenuService) { }

  menuPoints : MenuItems[];
  brand :String = "YST Brand";


  ngOnInit() {

this._menu.get()
  .subscribe(data => 
    { console.log("data",data);
      this.menuPoints = __values(data);
      console.log("menu",this.menuPoints);   
    });
   
}
}
```

Here the menu service, which returns the complete answer from server

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";

import { MenuItems} from "./models/menu-items";


@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MenuService {

constructor(private _http : HttpClient) { }

_url = "http://activity:8080/yardstickservice/rest/api/menu";

public get()  {
  return  this._http.get<MenuItems>(this._url);
}
```

and here is the component.html:

```
<div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-primary text-light">
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="nav-item dropdown" *ngFor="let item of menuPoints">
    <a *ngIf="item.childmenu; else submenu" class="text-light nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">{{item.itemtext}} </a>
    <ng-template #submenu>
      <!--submenu template-->
      <a  class="text-light nav-link" href="#">{{item.itemtext}}</a>
    </ng-template>
    <div *ngIf="item.childmenu" class="dropdown-menu text-light bg-primary">
        <a *ngFor="let subitem of item.childmenu" class="dropdown-item taxt-light" href="#">{{subitem.itemtext}}</a>
      </div>
  </li> 
</ul>
</nav>

</div>
```

This all works fine, only 1 time.
Logging on the console shows me, "data" contains the requested data.
"menuPoints" contains an array (don't know, what)
When I click a menu item, I lose the menu, pressing F5 brings it back.
I think I'm wrong with the "__values(data)". How can I get the retrieved data?

Comment: Do you really need the `__values`? If you change your service to `return  this._http.get<MenuItems[]>(this._url);` (add `[]` as you are returning an array), it should work I think.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a better approach:

**Service:** expose the data as an observable property (catch & rethrow error if any)

```
export class MenuService {
    menuItems$ = this._http.get<MenuItem[]>(this._url)
       .pipe(
            catchError(err => {
              console.error(err);
              return throwError(err);
             })
         );
    constructor(...
```

**component.ts:**  (catch & log error if any)

```
menuItems$ = this._menuService.menuItems$.pipe(
    catchError(err => {
      this.errorMessage = err;
      return EMPTY;
    })
  );
  constructor(...
```

**component.html:** use the async pipe so Angular takes care of subscribe/unsubscribe

```
 *ngFor="let item of menuItems$ | async"
```